# Gas estimation error during calling the funtion

Tags: ethereum, solidity

// I am getting gas estimation error while calling the function "drawNumbers". Can anyone please explain why I'm getting this error

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract ABC{
    uint max = 3;
    uint[] numbers;
    mapping(uint => bool) isNFTWon;
    function drawNumbers() public returns (uint256[] memory) {
        for(uint i=0; i<max; i++){
            uint Ids = uint (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, msg.sender))) % 1000;
            if(isNFTWon[Ids] == true){
                i -= 1;
                continue;
            }
            isNFTWon[Ids] = true;
            numbers.push(Ids);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

// I'm getting this error-----

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (20000000)" }

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code. you might not have enough funds

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that your transaction is going to be reverted. There is probably some requirement state failure or call failure.

The problem is seems like on line

```
i -= 1;
```

i is uint variable and when you decrementing the value of i, can underflow but with solidity version 0.8+ there is overflow/underflow check by default. If you want to try to better understand the problem is you can simply decrease your solidity version under 0.8 or bracket these lines like

```
unchecked {
  i -= 1;
}
```

If value of i will rise to uint max. then we can decide that the problem caused by that.

Comment: but @Erim, after 2 or 3 times calling the function it gives the gas exceeds error. Can you please tell me about why it gets out of gas quickly  ?

Comment: keccak256 is very expensive operation. If you increase the gas limit it will continue work. :) Also if you give upvote ill appreciate :)